# What do the seasons mean?

Tags: meaning, seasons

It's the last day of Summer, and a question came to my mind; In Greek, every season has a meaning:

```
Άνοιξη    - ανοίγουν τα λουλούδια // the flowers 'open'
Καλοκαίρι - καλός καιρός          // good weather
Φθινόπωρο - φθήνουν τα οπωρικά    // the fruits 'decline'
Χειμώνας  - χειμα = κρύο,ψύχος    // an ancient word, had to ask mama
```

But what about the English ones? The only results I get from Google are some ridiculous pages - like what is the inner meaning for me personally and stuff..Come someone explain? Or if they don't have, state it in an answer...

Comment: *Spring* and (American) *Fall* are about plants, while the others are much older

Comment: @Henry I would love to see an answer explaining the mystery ... :P

Comment: ψύχος = *psychos*  Interesting, wonder if there's undertones of dying.

Comment: ψύχος means cold @HowardPautz and it's pronounced *psechos*.. :) Hmm, I wonder too, but my mom didn't mention something like this. Unfortunately, she is located at the other corner of the earth right now, so I cannot ask her (or hug her). :) :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few snippets from an interesting [article by Daven Hiskey](http://www.todayifoundout.com/index.php/2013/02/why-we-call-the-seasons-summer-autumn-winter-and-spring/).

**Winter:**

> [...]  probably comes from the Proto-Indo-European (PIE) *wed, meaning **“wet”**.  Alternatively, it may come from the PIE *wind-, meaning **“white”**

**Spring:**

> plants **springing** from the ground [...]

**Summer:**

> [...]  a variant of the Proto-Indo-European *sem- meaning **“together / one”**

**Autumn:**

> [...]  it’s thought “autumnus” probably came from an Etruscan word and is possibly related to the Latin “augere” meaning **“to increase”** [...]  and became common in the 16th century, about the same time calling it “fall” popped up as the name for the season.  Before calling the season “autumn” or “fall” in English, it was called “harvest”.

Note 1. Here I'm focusing on word meanings  whereas the original article is more wide-ranging and discusses the words' evolution.

Note 2. As discussed in comments this is a brief summary of someone else's work. I don't want to duplicate the entire article here. The only changes from original is the use of bold text to highlight what I think most interesting.

Comment: PIE -> ???. Spring makes sense! +1...~ Autumn -> I don't understand.. :/

Comment: Proto-Indo-European (PIE) Language

Comment: Ah a language..Why you used an asterisk before wind? Hmm, I would advice to transfer the gist of that link for Autumn, here, since link-answers are no good, especially when the link dies..

Comment: I am trying to keep it brief as I don't want to repeat the whole article.

Comment: That's why I said the gist. Right now Autumn doesn't make any sense, so I may be able to figure that out by brute-forcing the article, but the future users won't be able to do that in case of link failure, but u know better..

Comment: @gsamaras: an asterisk before a word means that we don't have any record of the actual word; it has been reconstructed from its descendants in modern languages.

Comment: @suməlic the asterisk seems to have disappeared, but thanks!

Comment: There were some typos in first version !

Comment: @gsamaras The asterisks are important, and should be there. Not only because these are direct quotes from the article [and should thus be verbatim, right or wrong] but also because they are actually correct, as sumelic has explained in an earlier comment.

Comment: @andrew-leach and suməlic - I've fixed up quotes to use exact original text including asterisks. Apologies for any confusion - I had meant to clean up format only not change meaning.

Comment: @gsamaras "Right now Autumn doesn't make any sense" ... The article says the ' Latin “augere” ' means ' “to increase".'  Its next paragraph notes 'before calling the season “autumn” or “fall” in English, it was called “harvest”.'  So, I read the connection reflecting that a harvest increases the food supply - clearly a significant, fundamental thing.

Comment: @HowardPautz you had to click on the article for that. That's not how answering in StackExcahnge should be. Same goes for Summer, I guess, thanks though!

Comment: @gsamaras - indeed, links to other sites are not good and are discouraged for the very reason you mention. But it's all we have at the moment. ... and  trying to get permission from that article's author to reprint it here as part of an answer would likely be more effort than most of us would want to undertake. If you think it would help, you could do that and post your own answer, which is certainly OK.

Comment: Edited again to give some longer quotes, and couple of notes to explain approach.